# What is the minimum and maximum size of an Ethernet frame with split up

Tags: networking, ethernet

How do I calculated  the minimum and maximum size of an Ethernet frame with split up.We all know maximum size for Ehternet frame is 1518bytes but would be the with split up?

Answer (score 0):

The minimum and maximum frame size is mainly the constraints imposed by the traditional ethernet network at 10Mbps.  Since at 10M ethernet shares the same collision domain, a client needs to detect whether a collision had occurred before sending.  So, the minimum size is 64bytes at 10Mbps to ensure a collision can be detected within a time limit over certain distance over certain kind of cable specified in the standard.

Nowadays many machines have their own cable/link directly connecting to a switch/router and hence reducing their collision domain (no more collision-detect needed) down to just broadcast domain in the case for a VLAN.  Some vendors can support jumbo frames up to 64k in some cases.